# Calling an existing AsynTask from IntentService when App is closed

Tags: java, android, android-service, intentservice

I have `AsyncTask` that get a List of Images and upload them one by one to DropBox, and display  `notification` with progress.

```
public UploadImages(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> api, String dropboxPath,
            List<MyImages> imgList) {
..
..

}
```

It is working O.K, I call it from my `mainThread` in my main Activity :

```
UploadImages uploadImages  = new UploadImages(this, mApi, IMAGES_DIR, listOfImages);
        upload.execute();
```

I want that my app once a day (even if my App is closed) would download a list of images from DropBox and upload those images that written in file (if they exist on my device).

1. How can I implement it? 
   I thought about set an Alarm to start `IntentService` that will download this list, and in that `IntentService` to parse it and call to my UploadImages AsynTask with the parsed list...Can I do it?

I understand that calling to `AsynTask` is done from `mainThread`, and I will call it from `IntetService`.

1. Does it the right to use for that an `IntentService` (it work for 1-3 min) ?

Comment: Call asynctask as usual inside IntentService using new AsyncTask().execute();

Comment: Why use an `IntentService` to call an `AsyncTask`? That's totally unnecessary as an `IntentService` has its own worker thread. If you are simply trying to utilise existing code then put that code in a 'helper' class - you can then call it from your `AsyncTask` `doInBackground` method (when you need it) and also call it from the `IntentService` `onHandleIntent` method.

Comment: That is what I'am asking...I have working AsynTask, that should be triggered every X time, what is the best way to do it